# Selecting distinct elements from overlapping sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say I have a sequence of (possibly overlapping) sets:

$$S = [S_1, S_2, \dotsc S_M]$$

I wish to select a distinct member of each subset, as a sequence:
$$E = [e_1, e_2, \dotsc e_M]$$
$$e_i \in S_i $$
$$e_i \neq e_j  \quad\forall \; i \neq j $$

How can I (in general) determine when this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(CW answer to remove this question's "Unanswered" status)

---

As pointed out in the comments, this situation is dealt with by [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).